# Read and process only a part of a XML file

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have and XML file with 60k entities. I want to process it in batches of 20k. I am using SAX parser to parse the entities and store it in a list. 
I parsed 60k entities and stored it in a file/array/list and then process each separately. I dont think it is the best solution.

Is there any way to read only 20k entities from the XML file, process them and read the XML file again.

Comment: What you are describing should belong to your app logic. Are you aware that you can start or suspend sax parser at will. So why no suspend your parsing code after you have collected 20k entities?

Comment: Yes, thats what I have been thinking now. Will implement it and share the result. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Hi vtd-xml-author, It work, I had used the splitting logic inside my program.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use Multithreading concept. Create 3 thread, each thread has to read 20K data. Then another thread will read another 20k data.